# Allow windows service to be control from normal users accounts

Tags: batch-file, winapi, service

I am installing a windows service as a administrator and setting it to auto start

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc create DeepSleep  binpath= "C:\Users\Public\DeepSleep.exe" start= auto
```

Now i have to set permission to this service so that it can be controled by normal users also.

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>sc sdset DeepSleep D:(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;SY)(A;;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;BA)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;IU)(A;;CCLCSWLOCRRC;;;SU)(A;;RPWPCR;;;S-1-5-21-2133228432-2794320136-1823075350-1000)S:(AU;FA;CCDCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRSDRCWDWO;;;WD)
[SC] SetServiceObjectSecurity SUCCESS
```

Normal user still don't have permission

```
C:\Users\mandar>sc start DeepSleep 
[SC] StartService: OpenService FAILED 5:

Access is denied.
```

Is there anything missing from sc sdset?

Comment: are you run as `S-1-5-21-2133228432-2794320136-1823075350-1000` ? this look like *defaultuser0*

Comment: As you have not provided us with exactly which permissions you need setting it is impossible for us to provide safe guidance. _(You have probably copied your entire SDDL string from the internet too meaning that the SID string likely does not exist on your system either)_. To create settings for **B**uilt in **U**sers, _(which are missing in your string)_, you'd want something along these lines, `(A;;CCLCSWRPWPDTLOCRRC;;;BU)` for their permissions.